# Sum a Sum & Count column in 1 query or use PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Think my problem is I am trying to sum a count in the same query, could this be achieved in php to avoid this? The Records column displays count of records while the Costs sums the costs, this works great but I would like to then peform a sum of both these columns to show a grand total?

```
Select
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName As Name,
  Count(tblcases.CaseID)As Records,
  Sum(tblcases.CaseCommission) As Costs
From
  tblcontacts Inner Join
  tblcases On tblcontacts.ContactID =
    tblcases.ContactAssignedTo
Group By
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `With RollUp` at last. Single time scanning of table, so it's performance oriented.

```
Select
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName As Name,
  Count(tblcases.CaseID)As Records,
  Sum(tblcases.CaseCommission) As Costs
From
  tblcontacts Inner Join
  tblcases On tblcontacts.ContactID =
    tblcases.ContactAssignedTo
Group By
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName
WITH RollUP
```

[Refer here for more details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: Absolutely.  Much better than the manual approach using `UNION`.

Comment: @Romil, yes sorry for delay long weekend. That's much better thank you, I have just been testing this morning, haven't had much time yet but whenever I add a WHERE clause it outputs the summary row twice at table footer? I also notice at first glance it outputs the last row in the summary? For example if my last data row is 8 | Books | £2000 it adds a table summary below of 8 | Books | £10000 [column sum], I am trying to get it output  8 | Total| £10000. Will do some reading, is what I am trying to achieve possible do you know?

Thanks again

Comment: @gary, if you mention input and desired output in the post then it may help me to get a proper answer for you.

Comment: @Romil, Yes I am sorry I was just trying to get the structure correct before realising what was needed when I saw the output. I will keep researching why the WHERE adds 2 summary rows.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this in MySQL without adding another query and doing an `UNION` of them, e.g.:

```
Select
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName As Name,
  Count(tblcases.CaseID)As Records,
  Sum(tblcases.CaseCommission) As Costs
From
  tblcontacts Inner Join
  tblcases On tblcontacts.ContactID =
    tblcases.ContactAssignedTo
Group By
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName

UNION ALL

Select
  '--GRAND-TOTAL--',
  Count(tblcases.CaseID),
  Sum(tblcases.CaseCommission)
From
  tblcontacts Inner Join
  tblcases On tblcontacts.ContactID =
    tblcases.ContactAssignedTo
```

In this case, however, you'll probably be better performance off computing the grand totals in PHP, possibly while iterating through rows to build the table.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is brilliant its exactly what I wanted. Would I then have to create a completely new query to calculate row summary against Grand Total or is it possible to do that inside this also? <br />For example could I display count Records / Grand Total to display % - 10 records out of 100 would display 10%. Again many thanks for your quick & helpful insight.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I think I may have wasted your time I overlooked 1 vital piece! Your code gave me what I wanted, the query sums but I forgot these are filtered queries, so in fact the totals become incorrect once filtering has taken place! I use this with the jquery datatables but cannot get the footerfunction to work so thought I would try on my own! Would I need to go the php route taking the above into account? Thanks again.

Comment: You'll be better off splitting in two queries if you can... Sounds like what you're trying to do will be a maintenance nightmare if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping through the result set in PHP to display, you can sum the columns as you go through your loop.

For example

```
$sql = "your SQL here";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

$sum_records = $sum_costs = 0;

while ($r = mysql_fetch_object($query))
{
    // your other code here for whatever you're doing with the results
    $sum_records += $r->Records;
    $sum_costs += $r->Costs; 
}

// Now you have the two totals in $sum_records and $sum_costs.
```

Comment: Yes I agree using ROLLUP is the way to go using SQL, but I wasn't sure if the OP was asking how to SUM via PHP. Either way, he has a few choices now :)